# JS Array.prototype.sort() failing in Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, sorting, firefox

For some reason my sorting **only** fails (quietly) in Firefox. I believe I'm running into an issue where Firefox's implementation to satisfy the `Array.prototype.sort()` specification has subtle underlying differences compared to Chrome.

Thing is.... I can't see what's going wrong based on a few comments I've found elsewhere.

Can you see what's wrong? We're expecting "Dashboard" to arrive at the top and "Settings" at the bottom. Everything else should be alphabetically ordered. Works in Chrome, fails in Firefox:

```js
var cmsMenus = [{
    label: "dashboard",
  },
  {
    label: "settings",
  },
  {
    label: "item 2",
  },
  {
    label: "item 5",
  },
  {
    label: "item 8",
  },
];

//sort available menus
cmsMenus.sort((a, b) => {

  // push dashboard to top
  if (a.label.toLowerCase() == 'dashboard') {
    return -1;
  }
  // push everything above settings
  if (b.label.toLowerCase() == 'settings') {
    return -1;
  }
  // alphabetically order everything else
  if (a.label.toLowerCase() > b.label.toLowerCase()) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.label.toLowerCase() < b.label.toLowerCase()) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(cmsMenus);
```

Comment: Currently using Firefox 68 and I can confirm that when running your snippet here, dashboard is the first and settings the last item in the logged array. Edit: Works for me in chrome accordingly

Comment: The snippet works in Firefox for me.

Comment: Also works on FF 56. Regardless, you might consider just removing the `dashboard` and `settings` items, then sorting the rest, then appending dashboard, the array, and then settings - seems a *bit* odd to try to put that logic all into one sorting function

Comment: hey guys - thank-you for these hella quick responses :) After posting I tested this snippet here and it does work for me too! The only notable difference between this snippet and my real code are the presence of getters and setters from Vue - I'll see if I can show the issue here

Comment: Ah, but when I look at your sort comparator, I see that it can indeed fail for [a similar reason to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison) - it's not symmetric. Depending on the input, you might get a different sort order - you don't handle the case where  `a` is `settings` or `b` is `dashboard`, so a more optimised sort (non-bubble sort) that tries to be smart with the checks and tries to infer where things stand may be confused.

Comment: As a side note - you don't need to call `toString()` on a string. It's already a string, after all, so it's superfluous at best but it also makes reading this harder, as it adds unnecessary stuff to each line.

Comment: @VLAZ That is gold! Firefox does indeed rely on the sorting to be accurate for symetric edge-cases, thank-you. I'll remove the `toString()` calls - they we're added as I was considering if the vue getters() were causing issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider to use a symetrically sort and respect all comparison items, like `a` and `b` and return priority items with a delta.

```js
var cmsMenus = [{ label: "dashboard" }, { label: "settings" }, { label: "item 2" }, { label: "item 5" }, { label: "item 8" }];

cmsMenus.sort((a, b) => 
    (b.label.toLowerCase() === 'dashboard') - (a.label.toLowerCase() === 'dashboard') ||
    (a.label.toLowerCase() === 'settings') - (b.label.toLowerCase() === 'settings') ||
    a.label.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.label.toLowerCase())
);

console.log(cmsMenus);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'd drop the `.toString()` from everywhere but a good solution otherwise.

Comment: This is it - Firefox is less leniant when it comes to the symetry of ordering. Chrome was working, but after some testing it would of course mess-up the ordering if `cmsMenu` was re-ordered differently beforehand.

Comment: @TheMintyMate the size of the input might also matter. For smaller (e.g., less than ten) sizes of arrays one sorting algorithm might be employed and for lager (> 10) a different one. And each browser might use different algorithms, too, so you might see different behaviours in different *browsers* but also only for different number of items - it might be that with 15 items both Chrome and FF behave the same. Or only then they break.